# facebook app not linking to page

Tags: facebook

I have created an app in facebook and created a simple "hello world" canvas page and used the "Page Tabs" method of connecting to the app. I have followed the below tutorial.

http://www.hyperarts.com/blog/tutorial-add-an-iframe-application-to-your-facebook-fan-page-fall-2012/

The problem is connecting to the app from another facebook account as it does not show in search the list.

If I go to the page with the app while logged into my facebook account, the Hello world is working.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your app settings, click advanced tab on left and goto Sandbox Mode: and make sure this is disabled.

[image]

Comment: I have done this and waited all day to ensure it has been updated but still I cannot find my app when logged into another account.  I can't test it and develop it when I can only view it logged on as myself.

Comment: Can you link the app.  I will test for you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help, I can get to the app when I go to the link directly from another account, its just not appearing in search results.  Strange.  Im thinking I need to submit it somewhere before it is listed perhaps?

Comment: It used to be we had to submit to search, but i believe now that is all automatic now.  Make sure you have fully configured your app.